# How to style firefox toolbarbutton with type="menu"

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, xul

I have a Firefox extension with a toolbarbutton which when clicked displays a panel, I achieve this by setting its type to either "menu" or "panel". My problem is this type of button does not style in the same way as a standard button (a downwards arrow is displayed to indicate it can be expanded). Setting **class="toolbarbutton-1"** causes the button to appear almost correctly on Windows, but on Linux the icon is far too tall. My extension is available including the source at https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/tabcloud/ if that is useful.

My question is how should I style the toolbarbutton so it displays identically and with the correct height on all operating systems.

Comment: I don't understand. You shouldn't normally need to alter the style of a standard widget like that. If I look at DOM Inspector then its various toolbarbuttons look fine to me.

Comment: @Neil Try adding and removing the icon, in Windows it is very slightly taller than normal icons and stretches the bar slightly, in Linux it is far worse (see http://666kb.com/i/bqtay653warwlbkxj.png and http://666kb.com/i/bqtaygn89cmgn1h2v.png)

Comment: Not sure what the second picture was supposed to be but assuming the cloud icon is yours the toolbarbutton seems to have orient="vertical" defined on it for some reason.

Comment: The second image was just to show the height difference with the button removed. If I remove the class="toolbarbutton-1" then the arrow appears at the side of the icon rather than below, but this means on Firefox 4 that the button styling also disappears.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you want your button to look like one of the standard Firefox buttons? Sadly only one of the standard Firefox buttons use type="menu", and for some reason known only to themselves they worked around their own bug [here](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/browser/themes/gnomestripe/browser/browser.css?mark=676#675), [here](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/browser/themes/pinstripe/browser/browser.css?mark=656#655) and again [here](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/browser/themes/winstripe/browser/browser.css?mark=954#953)... I suggest you do the same in your own CSS.

Comment: Thanks for your effort on this. Sadly this still has issues if you enable text and icons on the toolbar, but as the built in bookmarks button has the same problem I doubt I can do much better easily.

Comment: Indeed. (By comparison, SeaMonkey gets this right, but then it has to, since it has e.g. the File button in the Mail & News window.)